# Decrypt apple-app-site-association in browser

Tags: javascript, ios, openssl, deep-linking, pkcs#7

I'm building a tool to verify deep links set up with Apple's apple-app-site-association files. In some cases, these files are pkcs7-mime encrypted.

Is there any way currently to decrypt these files entirely on the client? I've researched WebCrypto and similar tools but I can't find a solution.

Essentially, I'd like to replicate the following openssl command in JS:

`openssl smime -verify -inform DER -noverify -in apple-app-site-association.p7m`

This should successfully output valid JSON, such as:

```
{
"applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
        {
            "appID": "4MU37S3E4Q.com.couchsurfing.CouchSurfing",
            "paths": [
                        "NOT /people/*/*",
                        "NOT /users/*/*",
                        "NOT /events/*/*",
                        "NOT /events/past",
                        "NOT /events/attending",
                        "NOT /events/organizing",
                        "NOT /events/featured",
                        "NOT /users/confirmation",
                        "/users/*",
                        "/people/*",
                        "/events/*",
                        "/get_verified",
                        "/messages/*",
                        "/hosting",
                        "/mobile-hangouts"
                     ]
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [PKIjs](https://pkijs.org/). This is a pure JavaScript library implementing the formats that are used in PKI applications (signing, encryption, certificate requests, OCSP and TSP requests/responses). It is built on WebCrypto (Web Cryptography API) and requires no plug-ins to work in modern browsers.

Here is an example of decoding CMS/PKCS#7 files:

- [Demo](https://pkijs.org/examples/CMSSigned_complex_example.html)
- [Source](https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/PKI.js/tree/master/examples/CMSSignedComplexExample)

Comment: You should supply some of the code to use PKIjs. Otherwise, this is probably just a comment and not an answer.